# Databind() on gridview not working VB.net ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a datatable with verified 10 rows named dtable.  I attempt to bind it to my gridview and nothing shows up on my asp.net page. Why do these relatively simple few lines not populate my gridview?

```
    Dim con As SqlConnection = Nothing
    Dim dTable As DataTable
    Dim dataAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim sqlcmd As String
    .......
    dTable = New DataTable
    dataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd, con)
    dataAdapter.Fill(dTable)

    'DATATABLE at this point has 10 rows in it, I verified that at runtime

    gvUnitSystem.DataSource = dTable
    gvUnitSystem.DataBind()

End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you made sure that the GridView has AutoGenerateColumns set to true?

```
gvUnitSystem.AutoGenerateColumns = True
```

Comment: Im an idiot, I dont know why I overlook little things like that.  Yes that worked, and THANK you for correcting me on that.

Comment: before posting think then post

Answer (score 0):

This looks fine.  Are you auto-populating columns or have you manually added columns in the designer?  If it is the latter maybe none of the column fields match fields in your table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the con (connection string).